# GlassFish 4.1.1 and Apache Felix 5.4.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, osgi, apache-felix

I have a bunle which needs the new version of osgi (org.osgi.core 6.0.0). And I need to deploy this bundle in GF 4.1.1 open source version. By default in GF there is an old version of apache felix (4.2.1) so I replaced file glassfish4/glassfish/osgi/felix/bin/felix.jar to version 5.4.0 (I renamed org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar to felix.jar). After that I cleaned felix cache in domain and started GF. GF seems to work without any problems however I can't deploy my bundle as I get:

```
[2016-06-13T16:09:04.036+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=287 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1465823344036] [levelValue: 800] [[
  org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve com.temp [248](R 248.0): missing requirement [com.temp [248](R 248.0)] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))) Unresolved requirements: [[com.temp [248](R 248.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4111)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2117)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:998)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1175)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1153)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.processAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1146)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:456)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:263)]]
```

I've checked org.apache.felix.framework-5.4.0.jar there is default.properties and org.osgi.framework 1.8.0 package is exported. How to fix it?

Comment: Is the version of org.osgi.framework maybe overriden in some GF config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by editing `glassfish4/glassfish/config/osgi.properties` file

Comment: @MuzaffarMahmood I don't remember now, but I think osgi version.

Comment: I want to make a plugin based web application in java. What should i use? JavaEE or OSGI implementations like Apache Felix or Eclipse Equinox or something else?

Comment: @MuzaffarMahmood I wouldn't go OSGi, as OSGi is now dead, of course this is IMHO. The reason why I call its dead is JPMS that appeared in Java 9. So, modular system is now in java and there is no sense to use two modular systems (OSGI and JPMS) in one program. So OSGI is dead. You can use Java EE servlets with JPMS see here: https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2191 , however, it is not easy way to start from, because it took me about two months to make a framework to work with it. On the other hand JavaEE is much easier to start from, but there is no modularity.